# How to make the callback example run in bash?

Tags: bash, callback, pkill

I had read a discussion on bash's callback,jlliagre post an amazing example.
[callback example posted by jlliagre](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470440/is-the-callback-concept-of-programming-existent-in-bash)
Recite the main points here.
1.Create callback-example and run it on terminal with `./callback-example`.

```
#!/bin/bash
myCallback() {
    echo "I've been called at $(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S)"
}
# Set the handler
trap myCallback SIGUSR1
# Main loop. Does nothing useful, essentially waits
while true; do
    read foo
done
```

2.On another terminal, send the USR1 signal to the shell process.

```
$ pkill -USR1 callback-example
```

The author say :Each signal sent should trigger the display of lines like these ones in the first terminal:

```
I've been called at 20180925T003515
I've been called at 20180925T003517
```

I found that it never happen in my bash,how to fix it and run in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script appears in the process list as `/bin/bash ./callback-example` and not only as `./callback-example`.

Add option `-f` to your `pkill` command.

From `man pkill`:

> `-f`: The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the full  command line is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
kill -USR1 `ps aux|grep callbac[k] |awk '{print $2}'`
```

OR

```
pkill -USR1  -f  callback-example
```